# Read Text File with Multilevel Columns, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have below content in text file without header,

```
"Africa","10000"
"Brazil","5432"
"India","7687"

"US","87686","Import"
"Itally","2322","Export"
```

I needs to import above data into 3 Field Dataframe, I tried below script but fail

```
Data = pd.read_csv(FilePath, header=None, usecols=['One', 'Two', 'Three'], encoding='ISO-8859-1', dtype=object)

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Two', 'Three', 'One']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `names` instead `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for specify new columns names:

```
Data = pd.read_csv(FilePath, 
                   header=None, 
                   names=['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 
                   encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
                   dtype=object)
```

Test:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


temp='''"Africa","10000"
"Brazil","5432"
"India","7687"

"US","87686","Import"
"Itally","2322","Export"'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
Data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                   header=None, 
                   names=['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 
                   encoding='ISO-8859-1', 
                   dtype=object)
print (Data)
      One    Two   Three
0  Africa  10000     NaN
1  Brazil   5432     NaN
2   India   7687     NaN
3      US  87686  Import
4  Itally   2322  Export
```